# Стиль не применяется к родителю в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, style

У меня есть инпут, который находится в диве, при фокусе инпута долдно применяться стиль CSS к родителю див, но ничего не робит. Может кто-то помоxь и сказать что это за магия вне Хогвартса?
Заранее благодарен всем

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

input:focus div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="number2">На что делить</label>
  <input type="text" id="number2">
</div>
```

Comment: Стили работают только сверху вниз, в будущем появится селектор has который позволит сделать так как вы хотите, но пока что его нет.

Comment: @UserTest013, не появится

Comment: @Grundy, в сафари уже есть

Comment: @UserTest013 надеюсь появиться

Comment: @UserTest013, не знал. есть где про него? [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) = хм, интересно на сколько это общее решение, а не только придумка сафари

Comment: пока очень мало информации, но если есть сафари - попробовать уже можно https://css-irl.info/has-has-landed-in-safari/ . Не понятно даже как оно влияет на быстродействие, по идее очень негативно, но возможно что-то придумали с этим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

div:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
}

div input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="number2">На что делить</label>
  <input type="text" id="number2">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)